# Unable to compile Azure Function v4 out-of-process in VS 2022 Enterprise Version 17.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-functions

The Azure Function's `.csproj` definition is per the following snippet:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
     <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>true</_FunctionsSkipCleanOutput>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The Program.cs file's initialization is like the following code snippet:

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configure) =>
    {
        configure
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    })
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
          services.AddMyServices();
    })
    .Build();
```

The compiler issues the following error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error MSB4062 The "GenerateFunctionMetadata" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\myusername.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.sdk.functions\4.0.1\build..\tools\net6.0\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.MSBuild.dll.  Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.  MyApp.Functions C:\Users\myusername.nuget\packages\microsoft.azure.functions.worker.sdk\1.3.0\build\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk.targets   60

Would you please give a direction on fixing this problem?

Answer (score 5):

We need to remove Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions NuGet package reference to address this compile issue.